# Silverlight waiting for asynchronous call

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

I have a silverlight application that went it starts up, it needs to read a config file that a webservice returns.

So, in my main page, I want something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Config cfg = new Config();
    XDocument config = cfg.getConfig();
    //doing stuff with config here
    ...
}
```

The constructor for config calls readConfigAsnc and I have a method for the readcompleted that returns the xdocument. I want the readConfigCompleted called before execution continues in MainPage(). What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to separate this out into two methods.  Pass a function as a parameter of the getConfig, so like this:

```
cfg.getConfig( fcnToCall );
```

Later, in your code,

```
void fcnToCall( XDocument config )
{
    //Do stuff with config here...
}
```

---

Another option would be to use lambda expression if you want to retain your local variables:

```
Config cfg = new Config();
cfg.Callback += new Action<XDocument> action = s => 
        {
            XDocument cfg = s as XDocument;
            //Do stuff with config here...
        };
cfg.getConfig();
```

Comment: How do I pass the XDocument config parameter to fcnToCall? Right now, getConfig returns the XDocument config object.

Comment: Your getConfig(...) call needs to be modified to accept a Delegate.  When it is complete it should call that delegate.  You can look at my edit for an example of setting up a delegate that accepts one parameter (Action<XDocument> is a default one that does accepts that).

Comment: Or, you could just do my second one and use the lambda expression.

Comment: It looks like you only have one example there? Where is the separation of the two?

Comment: One uses a lambda expression, and the other just passes a function as a delegate.  They both do the same thing, but I like lambda expressions (if you're not familiar with them, look them up, they're very useful.)

Answer (score 3):

Why not separate out the methods? Instead of having all of this happen in the MainPage(), have the 'Do Stuff' happen in the GetConfigCompleted event.

Comment: Most of my things I want to do stuff with is in mainpage. Like UI elements and such.

Comment: The most powerful part of Silverlight is its databinding...I would bet that you can bind most of the things you are trying to manipulate to your view model, thus increasing your project's maintainability.